# Visual studio 2017 could not find LMCONS.H

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual studio 2017 coud not compile openscad with error:

> could not find LMCONS.H

Answer (score 0):

Compile your project with older sdk 10.0.14393.0 indtead of 10.0.15.063 or better **update** your visual studio to latest version and it will compile fine.